# Import Div from 2 different HTML files and add its content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have in one HTML this code and it works fine to do a basic math operation

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Facultad Contaduria</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_d.css"/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
     <meta name="description" content="Tile">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Words">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
   <body>
   <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="prim0">
     <p id="prim"> 10 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="seg0">
     <p id="seg"> 100 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="ter0">
     <p id="ter"></p>
    </div>
   </div>

<script>
var x = (1 * document.getElementById("seg").innerHTML) / document.getElementById("prim").innerHTML ;
document.getElementById("ter").innerHTML = x;
</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This code is very similar to other HMTL file i have, the problem is that i don't know how to add just one DIV `<p id="seg"> 100 </p>` from 2 different HTML files to another HTML file, the code i have is this, but it doesn't work

```html
<div id="gran_total">
      
      <p id="total"></p>
      
      <script type="text/javascript">
var x = (document.getElementById("seg").load("contaduria.html #seg") + document.getElementById("seg").load("derecho.html #seg")) ;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = x;
</script>
      
     </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm thinking a php solution might be better?

Comment: store values in any.js file and then access it in every html file, you just need to attach the js file.

Comment: @Brian that's a good option, but i need to read more about PHP, thanks!

Comment: @satyampathak I know how to attach js file into html, the thing i don't know is how to insert just a value from the js file into a HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaScript Approach**

Two Html you have :

**Html file 1 :**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="prim0">
    <p id="prim"> 10 </p>
</div>
<div id="seg0">
   <p id="seg"> 100 </p>
</div>
```

**Html File 2 :**

```
<div id="gran_total">
  <p id="total"></p>
</div>
```

**Write a JavaScript file :**

```
  var p1 = document.getElementById('prim').innerHTML; //First take innerHTML which will be in string, from  file 1
  var p2 = document.getElementById('seg').innerHTML;  //First take innerHTML which will be in string, from  file 2
  p1 = Number(p1); // Convert text into number
  p2 = Number(p2);
  var total = p1 + p2 ;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
```

**Note** :  P returns text so we need to convert it into  number ..

**Attach your javascript file in both html you will get the value in total box**

Comment: Thanks! that helped